# Make Matplolib plot discontinuous where Y value is 0

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have a plot that looks the one shown below.
[image]

However, my problem is that I want line breaks(discontinuous) wherever the Y value drops to 0. I have tried replacing the 0 with `np.nan`, `'nan'` ,`float('nan')` and none of them seem to solve my issue.
The plotting script is given below.

```
#noise_rms is a 1D array with y axis values
i_array = np.linspace(72.335, 103.015, 768)
plt.plot(i_array, noise_rms, color='black')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution (maybe not the most elegant) would just be to transform both the x and y to exclude y==0. You can do this using a numpy mask or simply list comprehension.